# How do i use invoke on a static method?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace HardwareMonitoring
{
    class Hardware
    {
        public static Form1 form1;
        public static CpuTemperature settings;
        public static ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;

        public Hardware(Form1 f1)
        {
            form1 = f1;

            settings = new CpuTemperature(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "/intelcpu/0/temperature/0/values", "H4sIAAAAAAAEAOy9B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Iu6//MH37x79i9/+NX6N3/TJm9/5f/01fw1+fosnv+A/+OlfS37/jZ/s/Lpv9fff6Ml/NTef/yZPnozc5679b+i193//TQZ+/w2Dd+P9/sZeX/67v/GTf/b3iP3u4/ObBL//73+i+f039+D8Zk/+xz/e/P6beu2TQZju8yH8f6OgzcvPv/U3/Rb8+z/0f/9b/+yfaOn8079X6fr6Cws7ln/iHzNwflPv99/wyS/+xY4+v/evcJ+733+jJ5//Cw7/4ndy9Im3+U2e/Fbnrk31C93vrt/fyPvdb+N//hsF7/4/AQAA//9NLZZ8WAIAAA==" },
                { "/intelcpu/0/load/0/values", "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" },
            });
            searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration");
            videoCardType("ati", "nvidia", f1.lb4());
        }

        public static void cpuView(bool pauseContinue, List<string> myData, ListBox lb1, Button bt1, float? tempcpuv)
        {
            if (pauseContinue == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Computer myComputer = new Computer();
                myComputer = new Computer(settings) { CPUEnabled = true };

                myComputer.Open();
                Trace.WriteLine("");
                foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
                {
                    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                    {
                        hardwareItem.Update();
                        foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
                            subHardware.Update();

                        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                        {
                            settings.SetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                settings.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                                //label17.Text = sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";//String.Format("{0} Temperature = {1}c", sensor.Name, sensor.Value.HasValue ? sensor.Value.Value.ToString() : "no value");

                                myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString());
                                lb1.DataSource = null;

                                tempcpuv = sensor.Value;
                                if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                {
                                    Logger.Write("The Current CPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    bt1.Enabled = true;
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void gpuView(bool pauseContinue, List<string> myData, ListBox lb1, Button bt1, float? tempgpuv, Label lb4)
        {

            if (pauseContinue == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Computer computer = new Computer();
                computer.Open();
                computer.GPUEnabled = true;

                foreach (var hardwareItem in computer.Hardware)
                {
                    if (videoCardType("ati", "nvidia",lb4) == true)
                    {
                        HardwareType htype = HardwareType.GpuNvidia;

                        if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == htype)
                        {

                            foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                            {

                                if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                                {

                                    sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                    if (sensor.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                                    {

                                        /* else if (UpdatingLabel(sensor.Value.ToString(), label16.Text.Substring(0, label16.Text.Length - 1)))
                                         {
                                             //  Label8 = GpuText;
                                         }*/
                                        //myData = new List<string>();
                                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                        lb1.DataSource = null;
                                        //sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";
                                        tempgpuv = sensor.Value;
                                        //label8.Visible = true;
                                    }
                                    if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                    {
                                        Logger.Write("The Current Nvidia GPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                        bt1.Enabled = true;
                                    }
                                    //form1.Select();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HardwareType htype = HardwareType.GpuAti;

                        if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == htype)
                        {

                            foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                            {

                                if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                                {

                                    sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                    if (sensor.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                                    {

                                        tempgpuv = sensor.Value;
                                        //label8.Visible = true;
                                    }
                                    if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                    {
                                        Logger.Write("The Current Ati GPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value); // to check when writing to the log each second its writing the snesor value a lot of time in gpu and cpu
                                        // to check why to make that it will write every second or every n times once. and not a lot of times maybe to change the logger write place not in loop ?
                                        bt1.Enabled = true;
                                    }
                                    form1.Select();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

         public static bool videoCardType(string ati , string nvidia, Label lb4)
        {
            bool atiNvidia = false;
            string graphicsCard = string.Empty;
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (PropertyData property in mo.Properties)
                {
                    if (property.Name == "Description")
                    {
                        graphicsCard = property.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (graphicsCard.Contains("NVIDIA") || graphicsCard.Contains("nvidia"))
            {
                atiNvidia = true;
                string toPrintNvidia = nvidia;
                if (graphicsCard.ToUpper().Contains(toPrintNvidia.ToUpper()))
                {
                    int startingIndex = graphicsCard.ToUpper().IndexOf(toPrintNvidia.ToUpper());
                    graphicsCard = graphicsCard.Substring(startingIndex, toPrintNvidia.Length);
                }

                lb4.Text = graphicsCard;
                return atiNvidia;
            }
            if (graphicsCard.Contains("ATI") || graphicsCard.Contains("ati"))
            {
                atiNvidia = false;
                string toPrintAti = ati;
                if (graphicsCard.ToUpper().Contains(toPrintAti.ToUpper()))
                {
                    int startingIndex = graphicsCard.ToUpper().IndexOf(toPrintAti.ToUpper());
                    graphicsCard = graphicsCard.Substring(startingIndex, toPrintAti.Length);
                }

                lb4.Text = graphicsCard;
                return atiNvidia;
            }

            return atiNvidia;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the class i have this method/function:

public static void gpuView

And in this method i have this line wich i want to invoke:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
```

But on this I'm getting the error:

> Error 1   Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static
>   method, or static field initializer

If i remove the static only make the function public then im getting the error on the Invoke:

> Error 1   'HardwareMonitoring.Hardware' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'HardwareMonitoring.Hardware' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And

> Error 2   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'HardwareMonitoring.Hardware.gpuView(bool,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List, System.Windows.Forms.ListBox,
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button, float?, System.Windows.Forms.Label)'

DoWork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        blinking_label();
                        NudgeMe();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                        stop_alarm = true;

                    }
                    data = new List<string>();
                    Hardware.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, data, listBox1, button1, tempCpuValue);
                    Hardware.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, data, listBox1, button1, tempGpuValue, label4);
                    listBox1.DataSource = data;
                    listBox1.Invalidate();

                }

            }
        }

And the two listBox events:

    private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
            {
                e.ItemHeight = 21;
            }

            private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Index == -1)
                {
                }
                else
                {

                    ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e);

                }
            }

And the ColorText class:


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace GatherLinks
    {
        class ColorText
        {


            public static void Texts(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
            {
                box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
                box.SelectionLength = 0;

                box.SelectionColor = color;
                box.AppendText(text);
                box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
            }

            public static void ColorListBox(List<string> data, DrawItemEventArgs e)
            {
                string strLeft = null;
                string strMid = "---";
                string strRight = null;
                if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))
                {
                    int index = data[e.Index].IndexOf(strMid);
                    strLeft = data[e.Index].Substring(0, index);
                    strRight = data[e.Index].Substring(index + strMid.Length);
                }

                using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16, FontStyle.Regular))
                {
                    float startPos;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(strLeft, f, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
                    startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft, f).Width;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(strMid, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
                    startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft + strMid, f).Width;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(strRight, f, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in Form1 load event I did:

```
h = new Hardware(this);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: What `Invoke()` function are you intending to call?

Comment: `this.Invoke` looks like the winforms-API for switching to the UI thread; What are you trying to do? why do you need to switch to the UI thread? Since you have some control instances, you could just use them... `lb1.Invoke(...)`

Comment: Im trying to update the listBox1 in Form1 . https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtdqnpemwistz5n/HardwareMonitoring.rar This is my project maybe someone can take a look at the part of my backgroundworker in Form1 i tried so many times and can't make it work. Im using a backgroundworker in Form1 and calling the functions from this class here to update the listBox1 in Form1 i want to update the listBox every second. But i can't figure out how to work with the backgroundworker tried with samples from the MSDN documents  so far nothing worked good.

Comment: I used the form1 in the new class the variable form1 with the invoke so im not getting the error but the backgroundworker is not working im getting many errors when exit my application win32 exceptions and others and the listBox in Form1 is not updating at all i have in Form1 two events in the bottom of the listBox one of them is using a function ColorListBox from another class where i color the listBox items but it never get to this event i used a breakpoint.

Comment: I don't see a need to use Invoke.  What's wrong with just calling mydata.Add()?

Comment: bmm6o then why the event drawitem and measure item of the listBox1 in Form1 never work i used a breakpoint there and it never stop there.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't see those functions here and I'm not going to download your entire project to find it.  You have to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: bmm6o i just added now the rest two events of the listBox code and the DoWork event code.

Answer (score 0):

From msdn docs

```
Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.
```

In order to use Invoke you need a control. Why not use lbl1.Invoke or one of the other controls being passed in?